# How would you change the code so that the child and parent run concurrently?

Tags: c, concurrency, operating-system

I am struggling to understand this question. Aren't the child and parent already running concurrently? Would the answer be to remove wait(NULL)? Please help.

Here the Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main (int args, char *argv[])
{
    pid_t fork_return;
    pid_t pid;
    pid=getpid();
    fork_return = fork();
    if (fork_return==-1) {
        // When fork() returns -1, an error has happened.
        printf("\nError creating process " );
        return 0;
    }

    if (fork_return==0) {
        // When fork() returns 0, we are in the child process.
        printf("\n\nThe values are Child ID = %d, Parent ID=%d\n", getpid(), getppid());
        execl("/bin/cat", "cat", "-b", "-v", "-t", argv[1], NULL);
    }
    else {
        // When fork() returns a positive number, we are in the parent process
        // and the return value is the PID of the newly created child process.
        wait(NULL);
        printf("\nChild Completes " );
        printf("\nIn the Parent Process\n");
        printf("Child Id = %d, Parent ID = %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does the line `wait(NULL);` do?

Comment: it wait the finish of the child process.

Comment: The child and parent are by definition running concurrently already. What makes you think they are not? Please describe the expected result and actual result.

Comment: `wait(NULL)` will block parent until any of it's child-processes terminate. Since it only has 1 child process, removing `wait(NULL)` will make child and parent process run concurrently.

Comment: `printf("Child Id = %d, Parent ID = %d\n", getpid(), getppid());` is it more appropriate to write `printf("Process Id = ... `